# how to set value to picker in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

hello i am working on xamarin forms 3.0 project and i am using picker to select values and using same for displaying user data to picker. Now my problem is that i am not able to show user selected value from database to picker.please help...

**code behind**

Below is the page constructor where i am passing my data to this page

```
public SummaryDetail(CpDetails cp)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (cp == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(cp));
            }
            GetLocations();
            BindingContext = cp;

            pklocation.SelectedIndex = cp.LocationId;
}
public async void GetLocations()
        {
        var loci = new List<Locations>();
        var client = new HttpClient();


        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("this is the link from where i am getting other values in picker");
        loci = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locations>>(json);

        pklocation.ItemsSource = loci;
    }
```

### **Xaml is**

```
<Picker x:Name="pklocation" Title="Select Location" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: GetLocations is async, but you are not awaiting it

Comment: Yah but still it is working my problem is that i am not able to show selected value in picker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Gerald Versluis for your help but i have done it by adding item using array and then i set SelectedIndex to selected value by comparing index in GetLocation() itself as below...

```
private int selectedLocation;
 public SummaryDetail(CpDetails cp)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetLocations();
            BindingContext = cp;                
            selectedLocation = cp.LocationId;    
}
public async void GetLocations()
        {
            var loci = new List<Locations>();
            var client = new HttpClient();   

            var json = await client.GetStringAsync("this is link");
            loci = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locations>>(json);
            foreach (var item in loci)
            {
                pklocation.Items.Add(item.Name);
                if (item.Id == selectedLoacion)
                    pklocation.SelectedIndex = item.Id;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`pklocation.SelectedIndex = cp.LocationId;` This seems not correct.

The `SelectedIndex` means the index in the collection that is in the `ItemsSource`. It does not magically know which Id to select. So you need to either find out what the index of the selected object is in the list and set the `SelectedIndex` to that. But what is probably easier, is to set the `SelectedItem`: `pklocation.SelectedItem = cp;`

In case that doesn't work, try this:

`pklocation.SelectedItem = ((List<Locations>)pklocation.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.LocationId == cp.LocationId);`

Although then I would recommend saving the `loci` variable on a more global level so you can refer to it from your `GetLocations` method.

More information on the Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/

Comment: Still i am not able to do this can you elaborate more about how to use selectedItem in picker to set value...sorry i am new in xamarin and this is my first project...@Gerald Versluis

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this? What have you tried?

Comment: I have done what you said that pkLocation.SelectedItem=cp but still picker is showing blank selected value. Is there any changes in xaml side?
Xaml is
<Picker x:Name="pklocation" Title="Select Location" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>

Comment: Updated the answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

For me the Binding to the ViewModel worked ok like this.

**XAML**

```
<Picker x:Name="gender" Title="Select Gender" TitleColor="Blue" SelectedItem="{Binding Gender}">
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
public Object _gender;

        public Object Gender
    {
        get { return _gender; }
        set
        {
            _gender = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

within function that retrieves data from database

```
Gender = (string)profile["gender"];
```